# Padding in href link is not clickable in firefox mobile (app) ? Bug?

Tags: html, css, debugging, firefox, mobile

I noticed that if I want to have the clickable area of the link equal to parent and use:

```
a {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

the area of padding is not clickable in `firefox mobile` (the app). If i delete padding to `a` and add it to parent then the area of padding is not clickable in all broweser (also dekstop). The problem is that i want a link equale to size of parent (but i want also that has a padding, otherwise all sizes are to small).

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english. Thanks a lot...

code:

```
<div class="tabchiaro">
 <b><a href="#link">Arco</a></b>
</div>

div.tabchiaro a {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 4px 0 4px 5px;
 width: 100%;
}


div.tabchiaro:hover {
 background-color: #d2ae71;
}


div.tabchiaro:hover a {
 color: #404040;
}
```

Comment: Add some small image to explain .. what it is showing and what you want?

Comment: @Moumit a screenshot do not think is helpful ... but I try to explain better: I have a div and a link inside, I want the clickable area of the link, the same as the div. Therefore as recommended in all questions use "width: 100%; height: 100% and display: block" and move the padding of div in link ... ok? In this way works very well in all  browsers eccept firefox browser app (you can try).. infact in firefox app the area of padding is not clickable... do you know what i mean ? i think that is a bug

Comment: I don't have access to firefox mobile app so I can't test it. I think you should check the computer properties the tag. Maybe the default CSS that it applies to 'a' tag is different and has something that's causing the problem

Comment: @NamanNehra what do you mean with "computer properties the tag" ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean computed CSS properties using getComputedStyle

Comment: Try display inline-block if it is not strictly necessary for you to use block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want the link to have a height of 100% without specifying the height of the parent element, in this case the div with class tabchiaro.

Some browser will automatically "fix" this for you so you might think your code is correct when it actually isn't.

If you want to fix that issue you have to:

1) Set a height to the parent element, something like

```
div.tabchiaro  {
   height:50px
}
```

2) Set the height of the anchor with pixels instead of percentage **because** in order for a percentage value to work for height, the parent's height must be determined. The only exception is the root element `<html>`, which can be a percentage height.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are proposing should work.

They can be other part of your code that is making the area not clickable. 
if you would provide a link of your project I can may be help you more.

Comment: yes.. i don't have other way... "mapsism.com/Archi_vulcanici" see the list menu in content (name of "archi vulcanici", volcanic arch) and try with app firefox. There's a problem when click on item (linked anchor in same page).. but this problem is not with other browser. I don't know if a problem with my iphone.. or problem with app...

Answer (score 0):

You better use the CSS animation properties such as webkit, -o- in order to support ur padding properties for all the browsers. Check out at w3schools for more.

Answer (score 0):

Check `display: inline-block`. Another idea is to check that box with `outline: 1px solid red`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix. Just do this:

```
<div class="tabchiaro">
 <b><a href="#link">Arco</a></b>
</div>

div.tabchiaro {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.tabchiaro, div.tabchiaro a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

div.tabchiaro a {
 padding: 12px 0 12px 10px;
}


div.tabchiaro:hover {
 background-color: #d2ae71;
}


div.tabchiaro:hover a {
 color: #404040;
}
```

**Note:** I exaggerated the padding a bit so it's more obvious.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3zf7bejq/1/

Let me know if it works! :)